# Use HTTP Interceptor on condition set in $rootScope

Tags: angularjs

I define an HTTP interceptor service using:

```
fooModule.service('myHttpInterceptor', function ($q, $rootScope) {
    // ...
})
```

I am able to push it in $httpProvider in the `config` block, and the interceptor works and is always enabled:

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
}]);
```

But I am unable to enable to interceptor **based on a config loaded in** `$rootScope`:

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider, $rootScope) {
    // $rootScope is undefined.
```

If I use `.run` instead of `.config`, I cannot use `$httpProvider`.

How can I use the HTTP Interceptor **only if** a variable found in $rootScope is set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - you can only inject providers to config functions, because they run prior to dependencies being created.

But what you can do instead is change your `myHttpInterceptor` to check for the property on root scope before doing any of its custom interceptor logic. That way, the interceptor will just not do anything when the property isn't set.

Comment: Thank you @GregL I figured this would be the way to go, I was just hoping I could keep the interceptor as modular as possible.

Comment: Having it depend on a `$rootScope` property isn't particularly modular. `$rootScope` is almost as bad as global scope. But I'm glad I helped you confirm the only real solution.

Comment: To clarify, I meant modular as in it can apply to a client but not another (which both use the same code base). The client configs are what is loaded in $rootScope and what the interceptor depends on @GregL .

Answer (score 2):

> How can I use the HTTP Interceptor only if a variable found in $rootScope is set?

To avoid polluting $rootScope, add a property to the interceptor factory:

Write the interceptor to check the `myInterceptEnable` property before proceeding:

```
app.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function() {
  return {
    'myInterceptEnable': false,
    // optional method
    'request': function(config) {
      if (!this.myInterceptEnable) return config;
      // do something on success
      return config;
    },    
    // optional method
   'requestError': function(rejection) {
      if (!this.myInterceptEnable) throw rejection;
      // do something on error
      if (canRecover(rejection)) {
        return responseOrNewPromise
      }
      return throw rejection;
    },    
    // optional method
    'response': function(response) {
      if (!this.myInterceptEnable) return response;
      // do something on success
      return response;
    },    
    // optional method
   'responseError': function(rejection) {
      if (!this.myInterceptEnable) throw rejection;
      // do something on error
      if (canRecover(rejection)) {
        return responseOrNewPromise
      }
      return throw rejection;
    }
  };
});
```

The interceptor then can be turned on or off by setting `myHttpInterceptor.myInterceptEnable` either `true` or `false`.

```
app.run(function(myInterceptor) {
    myInterceptor.myInterceptEnable = true;
});
```